# AJAX in a click event on a submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to ask you guys what would happen if I use an AJAX request when an user click on a submit buttons that changes the page. What would happen? Will the browser wait until the AJAX request is finished or it would depend on the internet speed of the user?

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming the AJAX request is a GET, this should execute much faster than the submit button click (a POST).....the AJAX GET should still be executed before the page reloads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of two things:

1. If you cancel the page-level submit event and handle the form via AJAX, the page won't refresh and your code will be responsible for managing the state of the DOM in response to the AJAX request.
2. If you *don't* cancel the page-level submit event, the AJAX request will be sent and then the page will reload.  In that case the AJAX request will be abandoned.  The server may or may not process it, the browser will ignore any response.

   > it would depend on the internet speed of the user

Never, ever rely on resource timing for managing asynchronous operations.  It's entirely unpredictable.  Asynchronous operations are generally handled with various forms of continuations or callbacks in various language constructs which either wait on another thread for a response or get queued to interrupt the current thread for a response.  Structure the logic accordingly.  Relying on resource timing is like using a `for` loop with an operation of a known speed to measure the passage of time.  It'll change in every instance.

Answer (score 1):

the ajax request is asynchronous so you will face a racing problem, most probably the page will change before you get a response to your ajax request, and if the page is completely different (not just a div showing) you won't get the response content.